# Statistical Function to Use To Understand Significant Differences - Categorical Variable & Two Numeric

Tags: statistics, numeric, anova, t-test, categorical

I am trying to test if there is a significant difference between patient volume and whether they are interested in "PopHealth" feature or not.

- The PopHealthInterested column is # of respondents interested in "PopHealth" feature that fall within the patient volume category
- NonPopHealthInterested column is # of respondents not interested in "PopHealth" feature that fall within the patient volume category.

What statistical test should I use to understand if the higher patient volume groups tend to go one way or another (want the feature or dont)

[Table I am working on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZlsSb.png)

Looked at t-test, ANOVA, etc.

Comment: If you are dealing with categorical data and wish to determine the relationship between two categorical variables, the chi-squared test is an appropriate tool to use.